# Postgres 9.1 wait events

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

Is there anything in Postgresql  9.1 similar to wait events dynamic views of oracle?
I need to find queries which are waiting for a long time, and the events they are blocked on.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't such a fine grained tracking available in Postgres (other than using DTrace which apparently gives a lot of information).

There is a whole chapter in the manual "Monitoring Database Activity"
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/monitoring.html

Another option is the module pg_stats_statements:
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pgstatstatements.html

Answer (score 1):

For 9.6 and 10 you can try PASH-Viewer to observe wait events in the chart. You can see top sql queries and top sessions in period of time.

It's free and open source.
[image]

Screenshots:
https://habrastorage.org/webt/4h/ac/nv/4hacnv4ty2shh41gw3srzhp9t0i.png
https://habrastorage.org/webt/f2/4s/yt/f24sytk_inxgiav3wuajcjjifro.png
https://habrastorage.org/webt/lw/yp/kg/lwypkg-wu4timhbp6ge7p3nf8ok.png

GitHub: https://github.com/dbacvetkov/PASH-Viewer

Comment: Just to clarify - from the GitHub link, are you involved in this product? If so, you should probably make note of that.

Comment: Yes, i took an opensource product for Oracle (ash-viewer) and rewrited it for postgresql.